# Google Glass - Showing AlertDialog for a few seconds

Tags: java, android, alert

I want to show a short alert dialog in my glass application, like "You reached your goal!" for a few seconds. Then it should disappear automatically. How can I implement this function?

I'm using google glass with software version xe17.3

Here is an example of that what I mean:

[image: Example of a short alert]

Answer (score 4):

Try this code for showing AlertDialog for a few seconds:

```
AlertDialog alert ;
Handler delayhandler;

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("My Title");
builder.setCancelable(true);
builder.setMessage("hello");

alert = builder.create();
alert.show();

delayhandler = new Handler();
delayhandler.postDelayed(mTask, 5000);


private Runnable mTask = new Runnable()
{   public void run()
    {   
        if (alert.isShowing()) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a WindowManagerBadTokenException with "Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application"

Comment: I edited my answer at: AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this); Does it work now?

Comment: cool it works now! Do you know how I get a alert for the whole screen like in my example image? Do I need a livecard for that?

Comment: I am glad it helps, i hope you will accept this answer :)